# Nested structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, structure

I have a structure in python and the code looks as follows:

```py
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "a,b")

tuple_to_send = MyStruct(
                     a=0x0001,
                     b=0x99
                )

format_ = "hi"
msg = struct.pack(format_, *tuple_to_send._asdict().values())

s1 = MyStruct._make(struct.unpack(format_, msg))
print (s1)
```

How can I pack and unpack a nested structure inside MyStruct?

```py
NStruct = namedtuple("NStruct", "c,d")

p = NStruct(c=0x0004, d=0x5)
```